# composer rest server fails to start after upgrade to composer 0.19.6

Tags: hyperledger-composer

docker logs -f rest shows the following

```
[2018-05-28 06:38:39] PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
[2018-05-28 06:38:39] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:composer-rest-server id:0
[2018-05-28 06:38:39] PM2 log: App name:composer-rest-server id:0 online
{ Error: Cannot find module 'base64-js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:7:11309)
    at t (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:177)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:7:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:7:11111)
    at t (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:177)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:48717)
    at t (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:177)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:40420)
    at t (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:177)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:16408)
    at t (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:177)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/composer/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:15877) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
[2018-05-28 06:38:41] PM2 log: App [composer-rest-server] with id [0] and pid [14], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
```

I installed base64-js via npm but still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Following on from the previous answer and comments:**

There has been a problem last week building the Docker Images for Composer, so the version with the "latest" tag is v0.19.5.

If you look at this page on Docker Hub you can see the problem:

https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/composer-rest-server/tags/

As a temporary measure, if you run these 2 docker commands you should get a v0.19.6 version of the image that will be compatible with your v0.19.6 installed modules.

`docker pull hyperledger/composer-rest-server:0.19.6-20180524041020`

`docker tag hyperledger/composer-rest-server:0.19.6-20180524041020 hyperledger/composer-rest-server:latest`

I would suggest using `docker rmi` to remove any existing composer-rest-server images before using the commands above.

**UPDATE After Later Comments - AND Appology**

I'm sorry - I thought this would work and that these versions would be compatible.

To get compatibility now, you could re-install everything to v0.19.5 and use the 'trick' above to pull a composer-rest-server v0.19.5 and rename to latest (having removed the earlier one first)

or

you could uninstall composer and install the date specific version to be compatible with the container version.  (you will need to restart fabric and re-deploy the network again.)  e.g. `npm install -g composer-cli@0.19.6-20180524041020`

I have not tested this!

Comment: I removed all rest images from docker and ran the two commands above. When trying to run the rest server I get the following           Unable to find image 'myorg/composer-rest-server:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for myorg/composer-rest-server, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.

Comment: The docker build command in Step 2 should create an image with the name *myorg/composer-rest-server*    " docker build -t myorg/composer-rest-server . "

Comment: still some tagging issue after running the build command - Discovering types from business network definition ...
Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.6) is not compatible with client (0.19.6-20180524041020)
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.6) is not compatible with client (0.19.6-20180524041020)
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.6) is not compatible with client (0.19.6-20180524041020)

Comment: I'm sorry - I just tested this at the same time as you and got the same error!!  - updating my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4067
A bad swagger-client npm module was published 3 days ago which caused the problem. A new version of swagger-client 3.8.6 has now been published to fix the problem.

Comment: now getting the following    Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.6) is not compatible with client (0.19.5)
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.6) is not compatible with client (0.19.5)

Comment: You need to make sure your composer-cli and/or application dependencies are at the same version or micro version higher than the runtime, so in your case your runtime is 0.19.6, so the cli or application dependencies need to be 0.19.6. In general you would need to be at 0.19.x where x >= 6