# Composer-rest-server 0.19.6 Cannot find module 'ieee754'

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm attempting to expose my deployed hyperledger composer business network to a rest api.

I've had successes in the pass with just issuing `composer-rest-server` and following the prompts that followed, but I seem to have problems exposing my network to a rest api with version 0.19.6.

The complete error message is as follows:

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ieee754'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ibm-jti/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:7:11355)
    at t (/Users/ibm-jti/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:177)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ibm-jti/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:7:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ibm-jti/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:7:11111)
    at t (/Users/ibm-jti/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:177)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ibm-jti/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/swagger-client/dist/index.js:1:48717)
```

What is module `ieee754`? and how should I approach to fix this issue?

#### Note: I am using fabric version 1.1 and composer 0.19.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer is close, but what you need is not a global install. Here is how I solved the issue and I am sure it will work for you as well (I have a Mac so this will be assuming a Linux system, but the general steps are the same).

## The Problem

The global module `composer-rest-server` doesn't have the package `ieee754` installed *local* to the global module.

## The Solution

We need to get to the location where the global module `composer-rest-server` is installed on our machine to install the dependency local to the module.

## The Exact Solution

1.) The global package for `composer-rest-server` is either at one of these two paths:

- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server (for me it was here)
- /usr/local/lib/node/composer-rest-server

2.) Hit `cmd` & `space` to pull up spotlight search and input `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` then hit 'enter' to see all of your global modules. Confirm that the `composer-rest-server` folder is there.

3.) Open a terminal window and enter:
`cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server` (if you confirm the folder is at that path)

4.) Run this command: `npm install ieee754 --save`

5.) Go back to where your original project is and you are good to go. Run the `composer-rest-server` command and it will be successful if you have your prerequisites all installed.

## Another (Possible) Problem

After fixing that the `composer-rest-server` command would run, but at the end of entering the information, it asked it would crash due to a version mismatch for the `node-gyp` binary or something like that.

What I had to do next is go back to that global module in the command line and:

1. Remove the `node_modules` folder with the command `rm -r node_modules`
2. Run `nvm ls` (assuming you have the node version manager installed) and ensure that you are using node v8.11.2
3. If not then enter `nvm use v8.11.2` (assuming you have it installed, if not install it on your machine)
4. Finally, I ran `npm install` to reinstall all of the dependencies in the `composer-rest-server` module

The above may or may not be necessary, but I'll put it just in case you face the same problem as me.

If you do the above steps your problem will be solved. [hossam abdallah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5735536/hossam-abdallah) was close, but you have to do a bit more footwork and actually locally install it in the global `composer-rest-server` module.

## UPDATE:

[Here is the issue thread for this problem.](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4067#issuecomment-392676706) It is has been solved.

Comment: Thanks @Benyam , the missing `ieee754` module was precisely what I was missing in the `composer-rest-server` node_module. For mac users of [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), the `node_modules` folder for global packages may be located in `~/.nvm/versions/node/[your_nodejs_version]/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server`

Answer (score 0):

you need to install it

> npm install -g ieee754

Answer (score 0):

See [composer rest server fails to start after upgrade to composer 0.19.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561259/composer-rest-server-fails-to-start-after-upgrade-to-composer-0-19-6)
for an explanation. Although the SO has a different symptom and a different environment, the reasons are the same.